# Experience with "Add-in Express" tool for streamlining MS Office Add-in development?

Tags: .net, ms-office, add-in

Any experiences anyone can share about this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good time saver.  They've solved some problems that you may have to solve yourself if you choose not to use them.  Add-in problems as you're probably aware, can be fist pounding at best.

I used Add-in Express for a little while, but ended up going with my own add-in code based on the [COM shim stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159894(office.11).aspx).  I needed more information as to what was going on during the registration process (because it was failing in a highly secure environment).  That was the only reason why I switched though.  Was pretty happy with the product and support.  Just needed to be "closer to the metal", as the kids say these days.